# How to implement a call repetition until a certain condition is met using project reactor?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactor

Is there any approach to do something like this using project reactor?

```
fetchSystemUpdates() // return Mono<List<>>
   .repeatUntil(List::isNotEmpty)
   .map(...) // when its not empty do some processing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve it is to use `expand` to repeat request until non-empty list is received and filter out empty results downstream.

```java
fetchSystemUpdates()
        // repeat until results are not empty
        .expand(res -> {
            if (!res.isEmpty()) {
                return Mono.empty(); // stop "repeat loop"
            }

            return fetchSystemUpdates()
                // add delay before making subsequent call  
                .delaySubscription(Duration.ofMillis(1000));
        })
        .filter(res -> !res.isEmpty()) // filter out non-empty results
        .single() // convert Flux to Mono
        .map(...); // when its not empty do some processing
    }
```

Comment: How can I add delay between requests in this case?

Comment: just use one of the reactive delay operator `Mono.delay()` or `delaySubscription()`. Check modified example.